what is the difference between using property vs function?
Gosu methods can be written as function or property in guidewire. but what is the situation to use these ?
When should we use property and when should we use function to fetch the data in guidewire ?

You may be able to avoid criticism and downvoting of your question(s) by adding concrete code examples to your questions.  This is presented as an "opinion" question but as the answers below show (in particular the answer for Edgar) there are concrete technical reasons for choosing Property access over function.

I would second Marty's advice. Questions are much easier to answer when you supply a concrete code example. In this case I would suggest adding the code you are talking about, describing why you chose to implement it as a property or a function, and then ask if others agree with your assessment. The way you asked this question forces the answerers to do most of the work for you (which typically results in less people answering).

The answers so far are a bit more about what a Property is.  I will attempt to answer when to use them.  A bit more background might help as well.
There are 2 scenarios for properties, a getter and a setter
property get Property() { return value or expression }

property set Property(val: type) { expression -> leads to assignment }

Properties also have a null test prior to execution, so if the object which the property is assigned to is null, the code is simplified as you don't need to test before the reference.  A get returns null and a set ignores the assignment.
The syntax is simplified as well,
var usecase = [object].Property
rather than 
var usecase = [object].getProperty()

[object].Property = usecase
rather than
[object].setProperty(usecase)

So usage of properties does a few things.  It makes the code more readable, less syntax and it makes it more reliable, assuming that a base object null tests would have to be written.
Certain usages are 'OOTB', i.e. properties of Entities can always be accessed either with the property or java syntax.  Other kinds of objects can implement properties.
In good Gosu, if a usage can leverage Properties it is a best practice to implement using Properties to reap the benefits of improved readability and reliability.

The main difference is:
Property: Represents a value or state. It is accessed like a variable (e.g., object.property). It is used to store data.
Function: Represents behavior or actions. It is invoked with parentheses (e.g., object.function()). It is used to perform operations or calculations.

To add onto aarif's answer, properties allow you to control access to a variable in your Gosu class. You can think of it as a way to quickly write a getter and setter for an otherwise private variable.
Another use case is to calculate a changing value based on a constant value, where it doesn't make sense to store the calculated value. With a property, you don't have to define the setter either if you want it to be read only. There are many other use cases for properties, but these are a few that are top of mind for me.
Easily create a property for a private variable:
private var _myVar1 : String as MyVar1
//implicitly creates a getter/setter and can be accessed as x.MyVar

private var _myVar2 : String as readonly MyVar2
//implicitly creates only the getter

Create a calculated field. You can define just a getter, thus making the property read only.
property get Age() : Integer {
  //Perform some logic to calculate Age based on date of birth and the current date
  //The Age property is not stored and is calculated each time the x.Age property is accessed
}

The full rundown is in the Gosu reference guide here (login required):
https://docs.guidewire.com/is/gosu/gosu/topics/c_instance-variable-as-property.html
